# why my program was not executed in firefox browser?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title> battleship games 1-d </title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <h1> Battleship war begins</h1>
  <script language=javascript>
    var randomLoc = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    var location1 = randomLoc;
    var location2 = location1 + 1;
    var location3 = location2 + 1;
    var guesses;
    var guesses = 0;
    var hits = 0;
    var issunk = false;
    while (issunk == false) {
      prompt("Ready,Aim,Fire!(enter a number between 0-6:)");
      if (guesses < 0 || guesses > 6) {
        alert("please enter a valid number");
      } else {
        guesses = guesses + 1;
      }
      if (guesses == location1 || guesses == location2 || guesses == location3) {
        alert("hit!");
        hits = hits + 1;
      } else {
        prompt("You are running out of chances");
      }
      if (hits == 3) {
        issunk == true;
        alert("you sink my battle ship");
      } else {
        alert("Miss");
      }
      var status = "You took" + guesses + "to sink my battleship" + "so you have a   accuracy of about:" + (3 / guesses);
      alert("status");

  </script>
  <p>This was my first game that was cerated in javascript</p>
</body>
```

HERE, is my code and only the html part of the code was execute in the browser and inside the script tag it doesn't execute on the browser.

Comment: Check your developer console, there should be an error about a missing `}` to close the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One have forgotten one curly bracket to close the while loop. Just add one } at the end of your script.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing bracket, see example https://jsfiddle.net/x34aotm6/

```
<body>
  <h1> Battleship war begins</h1>
  <script language=javascript>
    var randomLoc = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    var location1 = randomLoc;
    var location2 = location1 + 1;
    var location3 = location2 + 1;
    var guesses;
    var guesses = 0;
    var hits = 0;
    var issunk = false;
    while (issunk == false) {
      prompt("Ready,Aim,Fire!(enter a number between 0-6:)");
      if (guesses < 0 || guesses > 6) {
        alert("please enter a valid number");
      } else {
        guesses = guesses + 1;
      }
      if (guesses == location1 || guesses == location2 || guesses == location3) {
        alert("hit!");
        hits = hits + 1;
      } else {
        prompt("You are running out of chances");
      }
      if (hits == 3) {
        issunk == true;
        alert("you sink my battle ship");
      } else {
        alert("Miss");
      }
    } //add curly brace here
    var status = "You took" + guesses + "to sink my battleship" + "so you have a   accuracy of about:" + (3 / guesses);
    alert("status");

  </script>
  <p>This was my first game that was cerated in javascript</p>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks and my code was executed and i have one more classification please clear that  also "can i execute only a js program alone in a browser

Comment: well you need a .html page to land on, it can contain only javascript though.